# WP-Syntax plugin not working

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I am new to wordpress (installed yesterday for first time). In order to add syntax highlighting i installed the WP-Syntax plugin and i copied pasted the following snippet in the edit post window. Its copied from the usage examples.

```
<pre lang="php">
<div id="foo">
<?php
function foo() {
echo "Hello World!\\n";
}
?>
</div>
</pre>
```

However when i preview it on the main site i end up seeing the following as it is, whereas i was expecting to see highlighted php code. Could anyone point out what could be the issue?

Comment: Much probably the plugin is conflicting with another plugin or with your theme... Check [this troubleshoot guide](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-34-master-list) and also check your browser console to see if any errors are being dump. Close voting as [*too localized*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#close).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked to see if the correct style sheet is being loaded to change the highlighting? It appears to be a white background with some font styling for the different language. If you want something more than that, you will need to customize the css for it.

Comment: You're right, the css wasnt being loaded correctly. Problem was i was adding that snippet in 'text' view. I changed to 'html' view, pasted it and it worked. Thanks.